# T-SQL: How to Select Values in Value List that are NOT IN the Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of e-mail addresses, some of them are in my table, some of them are not. I want to select all e-mails from that list and whether they are in the table or not.

I can get users whose mail adresses are in the table like this:
`SELECT u.* FROM USERS u WHERE u.EMAIL IN ('email1', 'email2', 'email3')`

But how can I select values in that list which are not exist in the table?

Moreover, how can I select like this:

```
E-Mail | Status
email1 | Exist  
email2 | Exist  
email3 | Not Exist  
email4 | Exist
```

Comment: Do you mean T-SQL from Microsoft's SQL Server? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes, MS SQL Server. I'm using 2005 and 2008 R2 both.

Comment: Okay, in that case I recommend Martin Smith's answer. I asked because even SQL Server 2000 is still used a fair amount and his answer wouldn't work on that.

Comment: And with his edit, his answer would work even for all versions :)

Comment: Thank you hvd, if you didn't ask, Martin may wouldn't have edited. I didn't know SQL is running commands for remote server, my Studio is 2008 but remote server is 2005 so (VALUES) didn't work but (UNION ALL) did.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT email,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
                     FROM   Users U
                     WHERE  E.email = U.email) THEN 'Exist'
         ELSE 'Not Exist'
       END AS [Status]
FROM   (VALUES('email1'),
              ('email2'),
              ('email3'),
              ('email4')) E(email)
```

For previous versions you can do something similar with a derived table `UNION ALL`-ing the constants.

```
/*The SELECT list is the same as previously*/
FROM (
SELECT 'email1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'email2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'email3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'email4'
)  E(email)
```

Or if you want just the non-existing ones (as implied by the title) rather than the exact resultset given in the question, you can simply do this

```
SELECT email
FROM   (VALUES('email1'),
              ('email2'),
              ('email3'),
              ('email4')) E(email)  
EXCEPT
SELECT email
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to somehow create a table with these values and then use `NOT IN`. This can be done with a temporary table, a CTE (Common Table Expression) or a [Table Values Constructor](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/) (available in SQL-Server 2008):

```
SELECT email
FROM
    ( VALUES 
        ('email1')
      , ('email2')
      , ('email3')
    ) AS Checking (email)
WHERE email NOT IN 
      ( SELECT email 
        FROM Users
      )
```

The second result can be found with a `LEFT JOIN` or an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT email
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                          FROM Users u
                          WHERE u.email = Checking.email
                        ) 
            THEN 'Exists'
            ELSE 'Not exists'
       END AS status 
FROM
    ( VALUES 
        ('email1')
      , ('email2')
      , ('email3')
    ) AS Checking (email)
```

Comment: That gives the values in the table that are not in the list. The question asks it the other way around: the ones in the list that are not in the table.

Comment: With the edit, it still won't be right if `Users.email` is nullable (and we don't know if it is)

Comment: @hvd: You are right, we don't know if it is nullable. The query will answer correctly though.

Comment: Your second query will, your first won't. `WHERE 'a' IN ('b', NULL, 'c')` is `UNKNOWN` rather than `FALSE`, and `NOT UNKNOWN` is still `UNKNOWN`. In other words if any user's email address is `NULL`, the first query will not return anything.

Comment: @hvd: I know but that could be the "correct" behaviour for the OP :) Why else does he have Nulls in the column after all?

Comment: Yes, technically, there's a chance that when a user's email address is unknown, that user's happens to be one of the few email addresses in the OP's hardcoded list, *and* the OP wants to account for the possibility that it is one of those few email addresses. I approximate that chance low enough to discard that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a table with the list of emails to check. Then do this query:

```
SELECT E.Email, CASE WHEN U.Email IS NULL THEN 'Not Exists' ELSE 'Exists' END Status
FROM EmailsToCheck E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM Users) U
ON E.Email = U.Email
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to go with long way. Martin's answer did it.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not want to have the emails in the list that are in the database you'll can do the following:

```
select    u.name
        , u.EMAIL
        , a.emailadres
        , case when a.emailadres is null then 'Not exists'
               else 'Exists'
          end as 'Existence'
from      users u
          left join (          select 'email1' as emailadres
                     union all select 'email2'
                     union all select 'email3') a
            on  a.emailadres = u.EMAIL)
```

this way you'll get a result like

```
name | email  | emailadres | existence
-----|--------|------------|----------
NULL | NULL   | a@b.com    | Not exists
Jan  | j@j.nl | j@j.nl     | Exists
```

Using the IN or EXISTS operators are more heavy then the left join in this case.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is late but correct, too. I'm glad I didn't have to create a table for values.

Comment: `EXISTS` will be more efficient than outer join as it can short circuit. Yours can bring back the same address multiple times if there are duplicates in `Users`. See [Subqueries in CASE Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx) for some details as to how `EXISTS` is handled.

Answer (score 1):

Use  this : 
-- SQL Server 2008 or later

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM USERS AS U
Inner Join (
  SELECT   
    EMail, [Status]
  FROM
    (
      Values
        ('email1', 'Exist'),
        ('email2', 'Exist'),
        ('email3', 'Not Exist'),
        ('email4', 'Exist')
    )AS TempTableName (EMail, [Status])
  Where TempTableName.EMail IN ('email1','email2','email3')
) As TMP ON U.EMail = TMP.EMail
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work with all SQL versions.

```
SELECT  E.AccessCode ,
        CASE WHEN C.AccessCode IS NOT NULL THEN 'Exist'
             ELSE 'Not Exist'
        END AS [Status]
FROM    ( SELECT    '60552' AS AccessCode
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    '80630'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    '1611'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    '0000'
        ) AS E
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Credentials C ON E.AccessCode = c.AccessCode
```