# SELECT those not found in IN() list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with over 1000 tables (e.g Customers).

I have a query requiring details of a known list of customers (e.g by CustomerID - 1,79,14,100,123)

The IN() function is what I would like to use for the query.

I know to find customers that match the list, I would write:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN (1,79,14,100,123)
```

To find those that are not in the list, I would write

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (1,79,14,100,123)
```

**Question**

**How do I find the list of Customers that where NOT returned or did not find a match from the list?**

Suppose the Customers table only has (1,79,100). Then it would mean 14 and 123 will not be matched. How do I find those values that do not find a match.

I was simplifying in my example. My list of items has over 300 IDs, so using `WHERE` condition with a long list of `OR` would be cumbersome/clumsy. I have thought of combining with self LEFT JOIN and identifying the NULL paired values, which would be 14 and 123

Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Add another similar question for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113204/t-sql-how-to-select-values-in-value-list-that-are-not-in-the-table

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a derived table or temporary table for example to hold the list of `CustomerId` then find the non matching ones with `EXCEPT`.

The below uses a [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) as a derived table (compatible with SQL Server 2008+)

```
SELECT CustomerId
FROM   (VALUES(1),
              (79),
              (14),
              (100),
              (123)) V(CustomerId)
EXCEPT
SELECT CustomerId
FROM   Customers
```

Comment: Thank-you @Martin Smith. That answered it! Out of interest, would you know if there's an ANSI SQL compatable version?

Comment: @user919426 - `EXCEPT` is definitely ANSI SQL (though Oracle uses the non standard `MINUS`). I think table value constructors are included in some version of the standard as well.

Comment: Is there a Mysql version?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question and is wondering how to do this in PostgreSQL

```
VALUES (1),(79),(14),(100),(123) EXCEPT ALL SELECT "CustomerId" from "Customers";
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with `LEFT JOIN` but you may also use `not exists`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers c
WHERE not exists (select * from CustomerDetails ds where ds.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
```

Comment: Thanks, though I it does not answer the question as I want all CustomerIDs that were not matched from the list if CustomerIDs in the IN statement.