# Get Missing Month from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table that stores `EmployeeId, TourMonth, StartMonth, EndMonth`.

`TourMonth` represents the month, `1` represents January, `2` represents February etc.

I want to find the missing month between from given  `startdate` and `enddate` from this table. Given below example for employee 3071 from January to December the months February, April, July, September are missing. How can I get that result form the table?

```
EmployeeId   TourMonth   StartMonth                    EndMonth
---------    ---------   ---------                     --------
3071               1     2015-01-13 00:00:00.000       2015-01-14 00:00:00.000
3071               3     2015-03-15 00:00:00.000       2015-04-15 00:00:00.000
3071               5     2015-05-15 00:00:00.000       2015-06-15 00:00:00.000
3071               6     2015-06-15 00:00:00.000       2015-07-15 00:00:00.000
3071               8     2015-08-15 00:00:00.000       2015-09-15 00:00:00.000
3071               10    2015-10-15 00:00:00.000       2015-11-15 00:00:00.000
```

My desired output:

If I pass in `startdate = 2015-01-01` and `enddate = 2015-11-01` and `EmployeeId = 3071`, then I should get:

```
EmployeeId    MissingMonth
-----------   ------------
 3071          February 
 3071          April
 3071          July
 3071          September
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i have add edit the question

Answer (score 2):

for make code more straight, create table with months names:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[tbl_Months]') AND type IN ('U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Months]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Months] (
    [id] int NULL,
    [month] varchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of tbl_Months
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('1', 'January');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('2', 'February');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('3', 'March');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('4', 'April');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('5', 'May');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('6', 'June');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('7', 'July');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('8', 'August');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('9', 'September');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('10', 'October');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('11', 'November');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Months] VALUES ('12', 'December');
GO
COMMIT
```

Then simple select:

```
SELECT [id], [month] from tbl_Months 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TourMonth FROM table_name WHERE "some conditions")
```

I not explain WHERE some condition, because it could be many variants

- You can compare by date exactly - for example StartMonth = '2015-10-15' with start_date = '2015-10-16' can include this month, can not include depending from logic.
- or by portion of the date (MONTH) depending of Your logic

Comment: i do not want to create a `tbl_Months`

Comment: This is most compact way (not want create permanent table - create temporary)

But of course it can be realised and without creating table - check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113204/t-sql-how-to-select-values-in-value-list-that-are-not-in-the-table

pretty same task - How select element from list, which not presented in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the 1-12 month rows inline, but you might find a physical [date table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74957/best-approach-for-populating-date-dimension-table) quite useful.

Heres a simple inline example:

```
declare @EmployeeTours table (EmployeeId int, TourMonth int, StartMonth datetime, EndMonth datetime);
insert into @EmployeeTours
values
(3071, 1,    '2015-01-13 00:00:00.000',     '2015-01-14 00:00:00.000'),
(3071, 3,    '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000',     '2015-04-15 00:00:00.000'),
(3071, 5,    '2015-05-15 00:00:00.000',     '2015-06-15 00:00:00.000'),
(3071, 6,    '2015-06-15 00:00:00.000',     '2015-07-15 00:00:00.000'),
(3071, 8,    '2015-08-15 00:00:00.000',     '2015-09-15 00:00:00.000'),
(3071, 10,   '2015-10-15 00:00:00.000',     '2015-11-15 00:00:00.000')

declare @EmployeeId int = 3071,
        @StartMonth datetime = '2015-01-01',
        @EndMonth datetime = '2015-11-01';

select  @EmployeeId, datename(month, dateadd(month, d.TourMonth, 0)-1)
from    (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))d(TourMonth) 
left
join    @EmployeeTours et on 
        d.TourMonth = et.TourMonth and
        StartMonth >= @StartMonth and
        EndMonth <= @EndMonth and
        EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
where   et.EmployeeId is null
group
by      EmployeeId, d.TourMonth
```

Returns:

```
3071    February
3071    April
3071    July
3071    September
3071    October
3071    November
3071    December
```

Comment: that is great answer that i want but i have one table Employee that contain EmplyeeId and EmployeeName i want to display the employeeName with Inner Join how can i do this in this script where i need to change

Comment: @A.Goutam, you would use a *left* join from the dates table to employees and then filter for nulls on the employee side.