# SQL Find items in list that have no record in DB

Tags: sql, compare, record

I'm needing compare a list of items in a list and determine items that are missing from a database table.

For example, if my list contains these items:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
```

And the database table only has:

```
Item1
Item3
Item4
```

I would like the result to be "Item 2".

This syntax is obviously not correct but this is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT Item
FROM Items
WHERE (Item exists in my list but not in Items.Item)
```

Is this possible to do or do I need to have my list of items in a table to compare two tables? I don't have write access to this database so I can't create a table (that I'm aware of).

Comment: Nothing in SQL is called a "list".  What does your data look like?

Comment: Are you using a programming language for the list of items?  If so, you should tag that language as well...

Answer (score 2):

The general method is a `left join`, `not in`, or `not exists`:

```
select my.*
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) my(item)
where my.item not in (select i.item from items i.item);
```

Not all databases support the `values` table constructor, but all generally have some method for constructing a derived table with constant values.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution in [T-SQL: How to Select Values in Value List that are NOT IN the Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113204/t-sql-how-to-select-values-in-value-list-that-are-not-in-the-table)

I'm quite a novice when it comes to SQL so this was easier for me to understand and adapt it to my needs.