# How to select values in list that are NOT IN a Table using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a quite big list of strings (30k+) and I need to check which ones do not exist on a table using Entity Framework Core.

Something like this but without sending a request per item to check:

```
var notFoundItems = hugeList.Where(c => !tableToCheck.Any(x => x.Id == c)).ToList();
```

I found an answer but using [T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113204/t-sql-how-to-select-values-in-value-list-that-are-not-in-the-table)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that LINQ will produce a query per item.  Have you checked?

Comment: Well at least it's what my EF Core Oracle driver is executing

Comment: You should create a temp table (or a permanent table), empty and upload the `hugeList` and do the check on the server side. That T-SQL solution is going to have the same parameter limitation issue - you can't transmit 30k of strings in a single query that I am aware of. You could batch them into 2000 parameters at a time, but I think this is large enough not to do that.

Answer (score 5):

T-SQL can be a good approach, but in your case you would have to create a temporary table and make a join. 30k is not too many records, so it will probably be easier to compare records on the application side. In that case, you could do this:

```
var idList = tableToCheck.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
var notFoundItems = hugeList.Where(item => idList.All(id => id != item));
```

Since your strings from the database are IDs, you can do even better and use HashSet and Contains method, which has complexity of O(1):

```
var idSet = tableToCheck.Select(x => x.id).ToHashSet();
var notFoundItems = hugeList.Where(item => !idSet.Contains(item));
```

Ultimately, the performance depends on the size of the data set in the DB. If the DB table is huge and you would have to fetch millions of IDs, then the T-SQL approach will be faster.

Comment: Does this method had any limitation on max no of items in the list . On previous answer comments there are discussions about a limit of 2100 ?

Comment: No, Contains() in that example is translated to SQL and executed on DB side completely (LINQ to SQL). This example executes on DB side only the first select, and then filters elements on application side, thus it doesn't have that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a T-SQL solution, this is a good case for using a [Raw SQL Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). There will certainly be cases where a SQL query cannot be expressed in LINQ or the LINQ statement doesn't generate an optimized query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a select that search all the strings that exists on the table and put in a list. After you check what strings that not exists.

Example:

```
var foundItems = tableToCheck
                .Where(x => hugeList.Contains(x.id))
                .Select(x => x.id)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

var notFoundItems = hugeList.Where(c => !foundItems.Any(x => x == c)).ToList();
```

This way you do just one request to the db.

Comment: It's a solution but would require to iterate hugeList again which is not optimal.

Comment: It also won't work because `Contains` translates as `IN` or `== OR` and is limited to about 2100 parameters (at least, for MS SQL Server).

Comment: @NetMage If the EF driver is clever enough it will create multiple IN statements to circumvent this limitation, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @user2457870 Do you know of one that is? MS SQL Server driver isn't.

Comment: I'm not working with MS SQL Server but Devart for Oracle does it!

Comment: That actually woudld still be a bad approach - a proper driver would make a table values variable, upload the datas into it and juse a subselect. IN does not scale at all, sql server gets table scan VERY fast becuase of lack of statistics about the parameters.

Comment: Regarding iterating the list twice: Uploading the list to the server and joining will do that too - once on the client to create the SQL and once on the server. While it may need to be batched to handle the `IN` limitation I see this as an effective solution.