# SELECT the matching condition value along with the result from a multiple condition WHERE clause on the same column

Tags: sqlite

I think this is a pretty simple question but I can't figure out the right search terms to search this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113204/t-sql-how-to-select-values-in-value-list-that-are-not-in-the-table) is the most similar I could find, but it's the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

I have a query like this :

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE "val1%" OR column LIKE "val2%" OR column LIKE "val3%", ...so..on..and..on
```

Since it's an OR, only some of them will give matches from the column.

How can I return the matching LIKE clause with the query itself ? Like this :

```sql
SELECT *, (val1 or val2 or val3 - the matched val) FROM table WHERE column LIKE "val1%" OR column LIKE "val2%" OR column LIKE "val3%", ...so..on..and..on
```

Since the matching is by wildcard "%", I need to get the exact value that got the match.

If the table is this :

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 1 |
| John | 2 |
| Michael | 3 |
| Milinda | 4 |

And if the query is :

```sql
SELECT *, (the matched value) FROM table WHERE name LIKE "Mik%" OR name LIKE "Mic%" OR name LIKE "mia%"
```

It would return :

| name | age | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 1 | Mik |
| Michael | 3 | Mic |

Is this possible purely with an **SQLite** query ? I know this can be done later after obtaining the results, but want to remove that redundancy since SQLite will already be matching anyway.

Note: The table is very large. 100,000+ rows. So performance is a big factor to get result as fast as possible. Also the OR conditions can be 5 or 10 or 15+

Comment: How about splitting your query for each OR condition and later doing a UNION

Comment: @YogeshNaik Wouldn't that be slower than a single query ? I want to make the query as much fast as possible to execute. The table almost has 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE with all the match strings that you have and join to the table:

```
WITH cte(match) AS (VALUES ('Mik'), ('Mic'))
SELECT t.*, c.match
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.name LIKE c.match || '%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=73ac2d9d29751130a1be751b07864875).

Answer (score 1):

You may use a case expresssion. See working fiddle below:

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `name` VARCHAR(7),
  `age` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`name`, `age`)
VALUES
  ('Mike', '1'),
  ('John', '2'),
  ('Michael', '3'),
  ('Milinda', '4');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
     *, 
     CASE
         WHEN  name LIKE "Mik%" THEN "Mik"
         WHEN  name LIKE "Mic%" THEN "Mic"
         WHEN  name LIKE "mia%" THEN "mia"
     END as matched_value
FROM 
     my_table 
WHERE 
    name LIKE "Mik%" OR 
    name LIKE "Mic%" OR 
    name LIKE "mia%";
```

| name | age | matched_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 1 | Mik |
| Michael | 3 | Mic |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65KwwMPDWkMCzAcSG4ggrc/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! Is this the only way to achieve this ? I'm asking cause from my understanding of the problem, this is a very trivial problem since the matching is done already. When using CASE, there's additional matching to be done too.

Comment: @Subin I provided the answer based on the initial question. Based on your update, if you have a growing set of match values, then you may consider the answer proposed by forpas which may reduce the writing effort. If you are concerned about efficiency then you may use the `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` to garner debug details about each query. I've included some debug details [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e4d866bb20923fba3814113f5341ca86)

Comment: Sorry for not including that key points earlier. Thank you for that dbfiddle. It's very useful for understanding it deep. You've been very helpful :)